# Where should i put the django logic

Tags: django, forms, view

This is my form:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    upload_what = forms.URLField()
    upload_what.widget.attrs.update(size = '100')
```

So it's as simple as it gets, after the user pastes the `link` i need to check if the link represents a `cat` or a `dog` and depending on this finding i will upload a new `cat` or `dog` object in my database after i follow some specific steps.

My question is:

Where do i put all this logic? In the `view`, in the `form` or in the `model`? Remember that `cat` and `dog` models have different fields and there would be some processing in the background in order to figure out what those fields must be filled with.

I did read that the practice is to place all the logic in the `models` (fat models) but here i don't really know which model i'll be using when the user fires the `Submit` button.

For example, in my `views.py` it could look something like this:

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        link = form.cleaned_data['upload_what']
        if link == "cat":
            name = "some cat name"
            legs = #do some logic here
            # save cat to database
        elif link == "dog":
            #... some other logic here

            #save dog to database
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
```

Comment: Since this is a question that somewhat seeks an opinion: I follow a pattern where I create a separate module called `applogic.py`, placed in the same folder as `models.py`. This `applogic` module serves as a "bridge" between your views and your models, and contains logic like you described. In your case, I might define a function along the lines of `save_uploads(link, **form_data)`.  This keeps your views clean, and allows you to write re-usable, testable code that isn't buried inside of your views and form handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The `view.py` is the logic part of the Django. You can either declare a Class-based structure or use well-known methods.

[The class-based view:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/)

```
# some_app/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"
```

[The method-based view:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def aboutview(request):
   return render(request, 'about.html' )
```

Answer (score 0):

view.py is the place for your application logic, [View.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/)